# Read and divide multiple lines from Stdin

Tags: java, arrays, split, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read in two lines of input from stdin, and copy the items of the first line into one array, and the items of the second line into another array. The items in each line have spaces between them, which I use to differentiate between the items. An example of the input would be:

```
1 2 3
4 5
```

At the moment `12345` is stored in one array but I want the result to be this:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
arr2 = [4, 5];
```

How would I do this?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tester {   

  public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter lines:");  

    while(input.hasNext()) {

      String s = input.nextLine();
      String[] strArray = s.split(" ");

      int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];

      for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
        System.out.print(intArray[i]);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It there are exactly 2 lines, use an Array of arrays (two-dimensional arrays). 
If the number of lines is variable, use an ArrayList.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You ARE splitting it into two arrays... you don't do much with the arrays except for printing them behind each other in the same line, but you are splitting them.

Comment: an other way is define e symbol (a char) that identify the end of the line

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying. I have updated my question for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the parsing of a single line to a separate method:

```
private static int[] parseInts(String s) {
  String[] strArray = s.split(" ");

  int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];

  for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
  }
  return intArray;
}
```

After that, the code in `main` looks simpler:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter lines:");

  int[] line1Numbers = parseInts(input.nextLine());
  int[] line2Numbers = parseInts(input.nextLine());

  // For the remaining lines:
  while(input.hasNext()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    int[] numbers = parseInts(line);

    for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(intArray[i]);
    }
  }
}
```